# How do I exchange all of my currency for chips at once?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

I'd like to quickly exchange all of my NCR money for Tops chips instead of repeatedly clicking the exchange button. Is there a way to do this? I'd prefer not to click "8 chips for $20 NCR." 83 times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have high enough barter, the easiest thing to do is to simply sell the NCR money as one lump sum to a merchant with enough caps.  The exchange rate for caps at high barter is exactly the same as the exchange rate you get for chips (1:2.5 ratio).

[This mod](http://newvegas.nexusmods.com/downloads/file.php?id=40358) for the PC seems to allow you to exchange all your cash at once at the casinos.

Comment: All forms of money in the game (caps, NCR paper money and Legion coins) have a constant exchange rate, regardless of Barter skill.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no quick way to do that on consoles. The PC version might have a mod, but I don't know about those.

Comment: If you'll add information about the PC mod(s) I'll mark this as the accepted answer. :)